# NHibernate Criteria: concatenating two columns with an IN Expression

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

This is the SQL that I want to accomplish:

```
WHERE domain_nm + '\' + group_nm in ('DOMAINNAME\USERNAME1','DOMAINNAME2\USERNAME2')
```

I can't for the life of me find an appropriate Expression for this. And I don't think I can use two expressions as the domain name and the group name need to be concatenated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you not use two Expressions?

```
criteria
  .Add(Expression.In("DomainName", new string[] { "DOMAINNAME", "DOMAINNAME2" }))
  .Add(Expression.In("GroupName", new string[] { "USERNAME1", "USERNAME2" })
```

The other option is to use Expression.Sql.

Answer (score 2):

The Expression.Sql is as follows:

```
.Add(Expression.Sql(String.Format("{{alias}}.domain_nm + '\' + {{alias}}.group_nm in ({0})", getSqlInString(userGroups))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that two expressions will NOT work as I need a single expression.

DomainName and GroupName need to be concatenated before the in occurs.  Think user names on a domain account.  The DomainName and GroupName together are unique, not each separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a readonly formula field in your map. You will be able to query it that way. It would look like this using fluent nhibernate

```
Map(x => x.FullName).Formula("[domain_nm] + '\' + [group_nm]")
```

The query would then look like this

```
criteria.Add(Expression.In("FullName", new string[] { "DOMAINNAME\USERNAME1", "DOMAINNAME2\USERNAME2" }))
```